# TreeMap iteration does not give me sorted keys

Tags: java, collections, treemap

I have the below Java code excert. I am expecting to see the keys printed in a sorted manner (since I am using a TreeMap), but it is not sorting the keys. What I am missing?

**CODE:**

```
public class TreeMapTest {
    static TreeMap<String,String> li=new TreeMap<String,String>();

    static void readAndPrint(){
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry:li.entrySet() ){
            System.out.println(entry);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            String key = String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(100));
            String item = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(30);
            li.put(key,item);
            System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("inserting ({0},{1})",key,item));
        }

        readAndPrint();
    }
}
```

**Sample output:**

```
inserting (7,f4b66a)
inserting (2,5f417d)
inserting (51,90bb9f)
inserting (99,4bfb73)
inserting (41,a4e9d5)
inserting (14,9286d6)
inserting (44,ec4fbd)
inserting (58,e7dd3a)
inserting (69,c54e66)
inserting (0,d1fbfe)
0=d1fbfe
14=9286d6
2=5f417d
41=a4e9d5
44=ec4fbd
51=90bb9f
58=e7dd3a
69=c54e66
7=f4b66a
99=4bfb73
```

As you see I am not getting the elements sorted ( I sometimes have the output sorted and sometime have it not sorted as above!). What I am missing or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They *are* sorted, by the default sort order of Strings. Strings are ordered lexicographically, so `"14"` is considered less than `"2"`.

If you want numerical sort order, you should have made the keys Integers instead of Strings.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it whilst still keeping the keys as `String`s would be to use the [`Treemap(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Comparator)) constructor:

```
static TreeMap<String, String> li = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(Integer::valueOf));
```

Of course, making the keys `Integer`s also works.

Answer (score 1):

The map is ordering the keys lexicographically because they are strings (`1 < 4` for the first character, and so on for the other characters).

The simplest way is to have the keys as `Integer`s:

```
TreeMap<Integer,String> li=new TreeMap<>();
```

which will avoid the unnecessary need to convert the integer using `String.valueOf`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Integer based comparison then you need to have Integer keys in the map. Change

```
static TreeMap<String,String> li=new TreeMap<String,String>();
```

to

```
static TreeMap<Integer,String> li=new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
```

and , change put method to:

```
Integer key = new Random().nextInt(100);
String item = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(30);
li.put(key,item);
```